# Express server blocking form/data from chrome client even with cors middleware applied

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I have an express server that I have connected to MongoDB. The url here is localhost:1337, and I have a route localhost:1337/api/user/avatar that I want to post an image file to, to store an avatar on a user object. The npm package cors is setup properly as a middleware.

When I test the REST-endpoint with Postman it works fine. But when I try with the following upload component (built and run from chrome) I get this error in the Chrome console:

*upload:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:1337/api/user/avatar/5fc520239005616f09fb7d86' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import ImageUploading from "react-images-uploading"
import base64js from 'base64-js'
import axios from 'axios'
import backend from '../../api'

const Upload = ({userId}) => {

  const [images, setImages] = useState([])
  const maxNumber = 69

  useEffect(() => {
    // axios.post("./")
        if (images[0]) {
          var bodyFormData = new FormData();
          bodyFormData.append('avatar', images[0].file);
          console.log(bodyFormData)
          axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `localhost:1337/api/user/avatar/${userId}`,
            data: bodyFormData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
      return () => {
          // cleanup
     }
  }, [images])

  const onChange = (imageList, addUpdateIndex) => {
    // data for submit
    console.log(imageList, addUpdateIndex)
    // Function which adds the image to the database goes here.
    setImages(imageList)
  }

  return (
    <div className="Upload">
      <ImageUploading
        multiple
        value={images}
        onChange={onChange}
        maxNumber={maxNumber}
        dataURLKey="data_url"
      >
        {({
          imageList,
          onImageUpload,
          onImageRemoveAll,
          onImageUpdate,
          onImageRemove,
          isDragging,
          dragProps,
        }) => (
          // write your building UI
          <div className="upload__image-wrapper">
            <button
              style={isDragging ? { color: "red" } : null}
              onClick={onImageUpload}
              {...dragProps}
            >
              Click or Drop here
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button onClick={onImageRemoveAll}>Remove all images</button>
            {imageList.map((image, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="image-item">
                <img src={image.data_url} alt="" width="100" />
                <div className="image-item__btn-wrapper">
                  <button onClick={() => onImageUpdate(index)}>Update</button>
                  <button onClick={() => onImageRemove(index)}>Remove</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </ImageUploading>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Upload
```

Comment: Are you testing in postman to send data over localhost:3000 ?

Comment: Either way you probably have to supply cors header information from both the axios post, and the server must accept it too.

Comment: See ref: https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/cors/Authoritative-Guide-to-CORS-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-for-REST-APIs/

Answer (score 0):

The localhost URL was missing http://, which caused the error. I thought I had checked for that but apparently not.

Working code snippet:

```
  useEffect(() => {
        if (images[0]) {
          var bodyFormData = new FormData();
          bodyFormData.append('avatar', images[0].file);
          console.log(bodyFormData)
          axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `http://localhost:1337/api/user/avatar/${userId}`,
            data: bodyFormData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
        }
```